# why is $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{4(x^2-y)(2y-x^2)}{y^2} & y>0\\ 0 & y\leq 0.\end{cases}$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am reading a real analysis book which states that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{4(x^2-y)(2y-x^2)}{y^2} & \text{if } y>0\\
    0 & \text{if }y\leq 0.
\end{cases}$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, is not continuous at $(0,0)$ and if we fix any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and if we fix any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}.$

Now, it is easy to see that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ since if we set $x=0$ then $f(0,y)=\begin{cases}-8 &\text{ if }y>0\\ 0&\text{ if }y\leq 0\end{cases}$ and it is also easy to see that for any fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}$ the function $f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous because this last function is a polynomial in the $x$ variable.

What I don't understand is why this function (and also $f(x,\cdot)$) is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$; it seems to me that it should be continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x-\text{axis}\}$ infact if we consider $f(1,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{4(1-y)(2y-1)}{y^2}=\frac{-8y^2+12y-4}{y^2} & \text{if }y>0\\ 0&\text{if }y\leq 0\end{cases}$ it evaluates to $0$ for $y\leq 0$ but it goes to $-\infty$ for $y\to 0^+$.

Could someone please explain this to me? Why is $f$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ and why is $f(x,\cdot)$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for any fixed $x$?

Thanks.

Comment: You're right, the book (if you've cited it correctly) is wrong.

Comment: By the way, instead of just saying “a real analysis book”, it would be better to say *which* book it is.